# Chrome ignoring flex-basis in column layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, flexbox

I'm having trouble getting Chrome to pay attention to the flex-basis part of `flex: 1 1 25%` in a `flex-direction: column` layout. It works fine in a `row` layout.

The snippet below demonstrates the problem: the yellow, blue, and pink bars are flex-basis 50px, 25%, and 75%, shown in both column and row flex directions.

If you run it in Firefox (or IE11 or Edge) both column and row divide up the area as expected:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

But if you run it in Chrome (47) or Safari (9.0.3), the column layout on the left seems to ignore the flex-basis entirely -- the heights of the bars seem to have no relation to the flex-basis:

[image]

The *only* difference between left and right is the `flex-direction`.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.layout {
  flex: 1 1 100%; /* within .container */
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.exact {
  flex: 1 1 50px;
  background: #ffc;
}
.small {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  background: #cff;
}
.large {
  flex: 1 1 75%;
  background: #fcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layout column">
    <div class="exact">50px</div>
    <div class="small">25%</div>
    <div class="large">75%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout row">
    <div class="exact">50px</div>
    <div class="small">25%</div>
    <div class="large">75%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding `height: 100%` to `.column`, which makes Chrome pay attention to the flex-basis, but causes a different problem -- the flex gets bigger than its container:

```
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image: Chrome screenshot with height: 100%]

I gather this is a [long-standing webkit bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346275). Is there any way to work around it? (I'm trying to create some generalized layout components, so hard-coding specific numbers of children or specific pixel heights isn't workable.)

[EDIT] Here's an additional example showing the general problem (and avoiding the margin and total-greater-than-100% issues in the example above):

[image: Firefox vs Chrome nested flexboxes]

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.layout {
  flex: 1 1 100%; /* within its flex parent */
  display: flex;
  background: #ffc;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; /* attempted workaround for webkit */
}

.small {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  background: #cff;
}
.large {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  background: #fcf;
}

div {
  /* border/padding just makes divs easier to see --
     you can remove all of this without changing the problem */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="layout row">
        <div class="small">row: 30%</div>
        <div class="large layout column">
          <div class="small">row: 70%; col: 30%</div>
          <div class="large">row: 70%; col: 70%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe also related to [Flex basis 100% in column flexbox...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951913/flex-basis-100-in-column-flexbox-full-height-in-firefox-not-in-chrome) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32075092/647002) to it.

Comment: Also tried a version that avoids % heights/flex-basis altogether, using *only* pure flex (flex-grow). Same problem: Firefox flexes the main axis 70/30 as requested within a column container, Chrome does its own thing. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/medmunds/sc067gxe/)

Comment: Possible workaround by wrapping each flex child with a non-flex absolute wrapper (ugh!) here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/28#issuecomment-163441912. Problem may be that my .container's and .layout.row's children get their heights via cross-axis stretching (`align-items: stretch` flex default), and webkit doesn't treat that as a definite height.

Answer (score 8):

Three items to consider:

- **Sum of all heights greater than 100%**

  In your `.column` layout, you have three flex items. Their heights are `75% + 25% + 50px`. This by itself exceeds the `height: 100%` you applied. This does not cause an overflow because you have `flex-shrink` set to `1`.
- **Margin space**

  You have specified `margin: 10px` for both layouts. So there's an extra 20px of height from the top and bottom margins. In the `.column` layout, this *does* indeed cause an overflow on Chrome.

  Adjust for those extra 20px, and the overflow is gone:

  ```
  .column {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);   /* new */
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    background: #666;
    position: relative;
  }

  .layout {
    flex: 1 1 100%; /* within .container */
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
  }

  .row {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .column {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);   /* NEW */
  }

  .exact {
    flex: 1 1 50px;
    background: #ffc;
  }
  .small {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
    background: #cff;
  }
  .large {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
    background: #fcf;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="layout column">
      <div class="exact">50px</div>
      <div class="small">25%</div>
      <div class="large">75%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout row">
      <div class="exact">50px</div>
      <div class="small">25%</div>
      <div class="large">75%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- **Percentage Heights: Chrome / Safari vs Firefox / IE**

  The reason the flex items in Chrome / Safari don't recognize their percentage heights is because Webkit browsers are adhering to a more traditional interpretation of the spec:

  > [**CSS `height` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)
  >
  > **percentage**
  >  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to `auto`.
  >
  > **auto**
  >  The height depends on the values of other properties.

  In other words, if you want an element to have a percentage height, then you *must* specify a height on the parent.

  The traditional interpretation of this language is that "height" means the value of the `height` property. Although it's unclear from the language exactly what "height" means, the `height` property requirement has been the predominant implementation. I've never seen `min-height`, `max-height` or other forms of height work on a parent when dealing with percentage values.

  Recently, however, as noted in this question (and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33589469/3597276) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790812/3597276)), Firefox (and IE, apparently) has broadened its interpretation to accept `flex` heights, as well.

  It's not clear which browser is more compliant with the standard.

  It doesn't help matters that the `height` definition hasn't been updated since 1998 ([CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)).

  ***Bottom line, Chrome and Safari resolve percentage heights based on the value of the parent's `height` property. Firefox and IE11/Edge use the parent's computed flex height.***

  For now, the simplest cross-browser solution to this problem would be, in my view, using the `height` property across the board for percentage heights.

  UPDATE: More solutions here: [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I added an additional example that highlights the major problem I'm trying to solve while avoiding the first two issues you pointed out. The linked questions in your third point were really helpful, and led me to [this info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33589502/647002) on varying interpretations of definite and indefinite flex item sizes.

Comment: In your revised layouts, for Chrome to emulate FF, you would need to add `height: 100%` to `.row`.

Comment: Ah - perfect, thanks! I actually just moved `height: 100%` from `.column` to `.layout` -- which covers both columns and rows. So, any time I'm nesting flexboxes, sounds like adding an explicit 100% height is the magic incantation.